# How to use mex.h in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, compilation, mex

I am trying to create a mex.cpp file and I am unsure how to use the "mex.h" file. I have seen it used in other mex files and it seems like it is a standard .h file that contains some of the 'mex types' which allow for compatibility between Matlab and C++. Could someone provide some more clarification as to how I should 1) find the mex.h file and 2) use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calling [mex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) in MATLAB console should automatically setup needed headers. If you want to use your favorite compiler instead of MATLAB console then you should [find library and it headers and setup it as any other library](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-mex-files-with-the-microsoft-visual-c-ide.html).